# How to add a button in SSRS report and on click of button pass the tablix dataset to local server which will export the data set in excel

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

when we export the data to excel it contain lot of raw material like gauge and other unwanted things, but we need to export only the tablix data to excel.
How to export data in SSRS report and on click of button pass the tablix dataset to local server which will export the data set in excel.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a complicated approach. You can simply set the visibility of an object depending on the renderer.

So for your charts for example, setting the `hidden` property to something like

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", true, false)
```

Comment: how i can set the hidden property, so that i could get only relevant data in excel?

Comment: For everything that you do NOT want to export to excel, set the hidden property to the expression in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alan Schofield, it was really very helpful

Comment: But in case of tablix, suppose table has 5 rows and we need to hide 3 row in this case if we set this property{=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", true, false)} on 3rd row then when we export to excel, we saw space in between 2nd and 4th row. How to get rid of spaces in excel?

Comment: I would suggest you have two tablix objects, set one up for screen viewing (the one you have now) and another setup with just what you want exporting, then set hidden property as before but for the entire tablix. If this does not help then you need to open a new question as this was not in your original question which has been answered.